# index negative number in array in lua

Tags: arrays, lua, lua-table

problem: I have an array called `X`. `X[1:20]`. I initialized to 0 to start with.

I want to pass a  number to each element of array after adding 1 to it. So I read number  and store in local variable `z`. sometimes "number" can be positive and negative.

However, array is only for positive (i.e. x [1....20] ) 
When "number" is negative lua gives error message that "attempt to perform arithmetic on field '?' (a nil value).

What should I do?

```
local x= {}
local number
local z

for i = 1, 20 do 

    x [i] = 0;  -- array initialization 
end 

for y = 1, 5 do 

 z  = number   -- I am reading a "number" from hardware & it is a negative     integer number

 x[z] = x[z]+1 ; 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are reading x[z], not just assigning it.
A simple fix would be to give it a default value.
Example:

```
    x[z] = (x[z] or 0) + 1
```

This will make the code assume x[z] is equal to zero by default.

Comment: Thank you Benjamin. That works. However, If I want to actually use negative number and add it to array then what option do I have? Based on your answer every time I get negative number it assigns 0 to x[z] and I do not want that even though it makes code works. Do you think if I want to give negative number to array then I will have to define array from -20 to 20 instead of 1 to 20?

Comment: It depends, is there a particular value you want by default?
I'm confused on what it is you want exactly.
The "or 0" only means the default value is 0, and the + 1 at the end increments whatever was the previous value (0 if it didn't exist) by one.
This will act as if you had initialized your array in the range of ℝ (from -infinite to +infinite) and set the value of each of them to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Your initialization code is only setting the positive values of the array X to 0.  Simply modify the loop to initialize all the possible values of Z.

```
for i = -20, 20 do 
    x [i] = 0;  -- array initialization 
end
```

This assumes Z ranges from -20 to 20.

Negative index values work, but can sometimes lead to unexpected behavior when using the ipairs() function.  The ipairs() function will only iterate through the values of the table starting at index 1 until the first uninitialized (nil) entry.

```
t = {}
for i = -2, 2 do t[i] = i end

print("all values")
for i = -2, 2 do
  print(i, t[i])
end

print("positive integer values")
for k, v in ipairs(t) do
  print(k, v)
end
```

Gives the following results:

```
all values
-2  -2
-1  -1
0   0
1   1
2   2
positive integer values
1   1
2   2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't index tables using negative numbers in Lua. You have got few possibilities:

1. Type cast the index to string and index with this string. It will make your table associative (you can index with any string):

   ```
   z  = tostring(number)
   ```

   This is good if you do not have any boundaries for your indices
2. If you have limited interval of numbers (-20 to 20), you can do a transformation to the positive indices when accessing the values:

   ```
   MIN_VALUE = -20
   z = number - MIN_VALUE
   ```

   This approach should give better performance, since the array is addressed directly.

Answer (score 0):

You never set "number" to anything, therefore it gives you the error

> attempt to perform arithmetic on field '?' (a nil value)

Notice the words "a nil value", because this is why this error occurred. So next time set "number" to something, or add an "or ___" when trying to do something like calculations, or setting variables.